# Why does the problem "npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated" occur?

Tags: nodejs, npm

I have istalled latest version of node and npm. When I'm trying to install a global package (npm install -g firebase-tools), the terminal show me some errors. How can I solve the problem? Thanks.
[image]

Comment: Did you even click the link it provides?

Comment: yeah. but could not understand

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of teminal output - [edit] your question to paste the actual text.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in the latest version of `firebase-tools`, you can try using a slightly older version.

First, remove the installed version of `firebase-tools`

```
sudo npm uninstall -g firebase-tools
```

Now, install `npm i firebase-tools@7.13.0`

```
npm install -g firebase-tools@7.13.0
```

To confirm, type '' node in terminal and try to import the package using `require`, you should have a similar output as below

[image: terminal]

Comment: I tried your solution and also had same result in the terminal but could not see any any file or folder related to firebase in the expected folder.

Comment: That is obvious because you are doing a global install. If you want it only in the specific folder, open up a terminal in that folder and type npm install firebase-tools@7.13.0

Comment: It also shows "npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/sadhon/package.json'"